# Why do I get different stacktraces with java.lang.Throwable#getStackTrace and java.lang.Thread#getStackTrace

Tags: java, jvm

Here is code:

```
package stacktrace.test;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B.f();
    }
}

interface B {
    static void f() {
        C.f();
    }
}

interface C {
    static void f() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace1 = (new Exception()).getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace2 = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement x1 = stackTrace1[1];
        StackTraceElement x2 = stackTrace2[1];
        System.out.println(x1.getClassName());
        System.out.println(x2.getClassName());
    }
}
```

And output:

```
stacktrace.test.B
stacktrace.test.C
```

I'check the `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` it calls `(new Exception()).getStackTrace();`. In such case why I am getting different result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's different about it?

Comment: Well, the call stack is different, but in both cases you're accessing the second stack trace element.

Comment: @apangin, omg!. you're right. it's obvious! Could you please make your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've correctly noticed yourself, `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` calls `(new Exception()).getStackTrace();` This means that the stacktrace of the former will be exactly one frame longer.

If one method calls another, their stack traces cannot be the same by definition.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is going on, start by printing the entire stack trace item-by-item. Here is what you are going to get ([demo](https://ideone.com/n4jpD2)):

```
-- stackTrace1
C.f(Main.java:23)
B.f(Main.java:17)
A.main(Main.java:11)

-- stackTrace2
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1556)
C.f(Main.java:24)
B.f(Main.java:17)
A.main(Main.java:11)
```

Note that the only difference is in the initial item of the two stack traces: the second one contains an extra frame at the top.

It appears that the method that fills the stack of a `Throwable` excludes the frame with the constructor of the `Throwable` or its subclass, along with other methods called on the way to building it.

This makes sense, because when you see the stack trace of an exception you want to see the throwing method at the top, and disregard the fact that creating the exception required you to call its constructor.

Thread's `getStackTrace()` method, on the other hand, does not remove itself from the stack. That is what you see at the top of the stack when you print it out.

Comment: I agree that your suggestion makes sense, but it's only suggestion. It would be nice to get some official proof from the documentation.

Comment: @slesh The documentation for the two methods is identical. The difference is in the native code implementing `fillStackTrace` method of `Throwable`.